# How to play sound from one button based off of UIimageview image

Tags: swift, xcode, avaudioplayer

i've developed a fully working flash card app for kids.  It has a UIImageView that cycles thru 26 cards (abcs) via a gesture click and a music button that will play a sound for each image.  Right now i have this 100% working BUT the sound plays in an IF statement that has added an additional 400 lines of code.

An example of the music button:

```
        if (imageView.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "card1")))! {
            do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: aSound))
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't load sound file")
            }
        }
        else if (imageView.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "card2")))! {
            do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: bSound))
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't load sound file")
            }
        }
        else if (imageView.image?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "card3")))! {
            do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: cSound))
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't load sound file")
            }
        }
```

I know i could set a sound array with the sound files in it, but how would i tie it back to the card?  I cant set a tag property on an asset image can i?

Looking for a way to shorten the current code i have.

Comment: This question really belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.  When you post it there, show your code that loads the image into the imageView.

Comment: I saw your previous question. You should use a struct for your Card that holds an image and a sound. As you are cycling through, set the image and sound on the card. Use card.image for your UIImageView and play card.sound when they tap the button. It will greatly reduce your code.

Comment: Don - any examples?

Answer (score 0):

here is a way I would go about. Haven't tested it but it should get you there.! I use arrays, but Set or Dictionary would work.

1) Create a struct

```
struct Card {
    let soundURL: URL
    let image: UIImage
}
```

2) gather all the cards in an Array:

```
let cards: [Card] = {
    var collection = [Card]()
    let soundPaths: [String] = ["aSound", "bSound", "xSound", "zSound"]
    let cardNames: [String] = ["card1", "card2", "card25", "card26"]

    // array of all 26 urls
    var soundUrls: [URL] {
        var urls = [URL]()
        for path in soundPaths {
            urls.append(URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        }
        return urls
    }

    // array of all 26 images
    var cardImages: [UIImage] {
        var images = [UIImage]()
        for name in cardNames {
            guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: name) else { continue }
            images.append(image)
        }
        return images
    }

    // not the best approach but if you have sound and naming
    // in the order then:
    for idx in 0..<26 {
        let card = Card(soundURL: soundUrls[idx], image: cardImages[idx])
        collection.append(card)
    }

    return collection
}()
```

3) add an extension to UIImage to play the sound:

```
extension UIImage {
    func playSound() {
        let card = cards.filter { $0.image == self }.first
        if card != nil {
            do {
                let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: card!.soundURL)
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't load the sound file with error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you get your imageView.image, you should be able to just do:

```
imageView.image?.playSound()
```

Again I didn't test this, but I think the logic still stand. Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is completely wrong. Your image view is a *view*. You should not make any choices based on what it displays. You should make your choice based on something about your *data model*.

For example, let's say you have three images, and an array of three image names:

```
let images = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"]
var currentImageIndex = 0
```

And let's say you change the image index and display that image:

```
self.currentImageIndex = 1
self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:images[currentImageIndex])
```

Then the way you know which image is displayed is by looking at `currentImageIndex` — *not* by looking at the image view.

In real life, your model may be much more extensive, for example a struct and an array of structs. But the principle remains exactly the same. It is the *model* that tells you what to do, never the *interface*.